# Prevent Text scrolling and truncation in TextInput field

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have `TextInput` fields in my `React-Native` application and I cannot get the text in the field to not scroll and truncate the bottom of the text without setting the line height to something really large.

Here is a image of what is happening:

[image]

The styles props are as follows:

```
input: {
  height: 28, 
  paddingBottom: 0, 
  fontSize: 18,  
  color: '#000', 
  borderBottomWidth: 1.5,    
},
```

Is there a way I can force the text to not move within the `TextInput`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextInput in android seems to have a default paddingBottom set whereas iOS doesn't, because android have underline tag but ios doesn't .Different default paddings for each platform.

That why paddingBottom or paddings is not working properly.

Please check following [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6096)

Answer (score 4):

Please remove height props from style

```
input: {
  paddingBottom: 0, 
  fontSize: 18,  
  color: '#000', 
  borderBottomWidth: 1.5,    
},
```

I think it will help you

If you want to set please set it atleast 40

Comment: Why should that change things?  If I remove the height the lines are spaced out way to far apart.  But if the fields is a height of 28 and the font is a size of 18 why is there any scrolling?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur If height removed UI varies in different device, so paddingBottom: 0 is best solution I checked.

Answer (score 4):

Remove static height and set `paddingVertical : 7` also use `includeFontPadding:false`

here 7 is example you can set according to your choice.

sample style

```
textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.borderColor,
    color: colors.fontPrimary,
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    includeFontPadding:false,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
    paddingVertical:7,
  }
```

Comment: `includeFontPadding:false` made it for me

Answer (score 1):

The below code is solved my problem.

```
{
  includeFontPadding:false,
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
}
```

Hope it will work for you.